# API routes on react + express app giving 404 on Heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, heroku

So I built a simple mern app that works fine on my local environment, but when deploying to Heroku, it serves the react app fine but 404s on the API calls. I can't seems to figure out the issue. I'm sending requests using Axios. I checked the network requests and they all look good, but still come back 404. testing in postman also returned the same error.

Here's the server code... Any idea why this is failing?

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const Axios = require('axios');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
require('dotenv').config();

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;
const mongoUri = process.env.MONGODB_URI || 'mongodb://localhost:27017/book';

const app = express();

// Define middleware here
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
// Serve up static assets (usually on heroku)
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  app.use(express.static('client/build'));
}

const { Schema } = mongoose;
const bookSchema = new Schema({
  info: Schema.Types.Mixed,
});
const Book = mongoose.model('Book', bookSchema);

app.post('/api/search', (req, res) => {
  Axios.get(
    `https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=${req.body.term}`
  ).then(books => res.json(books.data.items));
});
app.post('/api/save', (req, res) => {
  const newBook = new Book({ info: req.body.book });
  newBook.save(err => {
    if (err) res.json(err);
    res.json({ status: true });
  });
});
app.post('/api/unsave', (req, res) => {
  Book.findByIdAndRemove(req.body.book._id, err => {
    if (err) res.json(err);
    res.json({ status: true });
  });
});
app.get('/api/saved', (req, res) => {
  Book.find({}, (err, books) => {
    if (err) res.json(err);
    res.json(books);
  });
});
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, './client/build/index.html'));
});

mongoose.connect(mongoUri, { useNewUrlParser: true });
const db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', function() {
  console.log('connected');
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(` ==> API server now on port ${PORT}!`);
});
```

and here's my package.json

```
{
    "name": "google-book",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "main": "server.js",
    "scripts": {
        "start": "if-env NODE_ENV=production && npm run start:prod || npm run start:dev",
        "start:prod": "node server.js",
        "start:dev": "concurrently \"nodemon --ignore 'client/*'\" \"npm run client\"",
        "client": "cd client && npm run start",
        "install": "cd client && npm install",
        "build": "cd client && npm run build",
        "heroku-postbuild": "npm run build"
    },
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "dependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.19.2",
        "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
        "concurrently": "^5.1.0",
        "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
        "express": "^4.17.1",
        "mongodb": "^3.5.3",
        "mongoose": "^5.9.1"
    }
}
```

My react routes in case that would be an issue

```
return (
    <div className="app">
      <Header />
      <Router>
        <Route exact path='/'>
          <Searchbar search={search} setSearch={setSearch} />
          {!search.term ? (
            <div className="message">
              <p>Search for a book or whatever</p>
            </div>
          ) : <SearchList results={search.results} />}
        </Route>
        <Route path='/saved'>
          <h2 className="title">Saved Books</h2>
          <SavedList />
        </Route>
        <Footer />
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: Anything in the heroku logs? What about the browser console? What does the front end code look like? Are you comfortable sharing the URL?

Comment: nothing useful in either log beyond 404 errors. It's really strange since it does work fine (proxied) in my local env. here's the link http://googly-book.herokuapp.com/

Here's what the request looks like:
Request URL: http://googly-book.herokuapp.com/api/search
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 404 Not Found
Remote Address: 18.211.160.51:80
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

Comment: What do the logs in Heroku say?

Comment: 2020-02-22T03:09:27.294399+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/api/search" host=googly-book.herokuapp.com request_id=aa832fd7-c70e-4317-b1ed-5a8128841ee3 fwd="76.247.3.91" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=404 bytes=417 protocol=http

Comment: Yea thats really weird... nothing is sticking out to me - everything looks like it should be working.

Comment: Yeah, it's a trip. thanks for looking!

Comment: What does your React router look like? I doubt it would be messing with... man, this is an odd one!

Comment: I tossed them in the question

Comment: I feel like the `app.get('*'` has something to do with it.. what happens if you change that to `app.get('/'` also, what happens if you comment this line out? `app.use(express.static('client/build'));` - seems like it's going to be one of those trial and error type of things.

Comment: I played with that a bit. I'll try again. Everything I read though recommends '*' as the catch all route when using react router.

Comment: Shouldnt have to worry about express routing while using React, though. Your React 404 route needs to be in your React routing.  React only hits your api on XHR requests, not when browsing (outside of the initial .html)

Comment: still 404ing with '/' for the react route. I'm open to trying anything else though. been bangin my head against this all evening.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure why this is happening to you.. I [created this repo](https://github.com/oze4/heroku-react-express-test) and [deployed it to Heroku](https://big-cake.herokuapp.com/) - I am able to use my "API" without 404...

Comment: Where you ever able to figure this out? Is your code in a repo somewhere that I can take a look at?

Comment: never did figure it out. here's the repo https://github.com/marcjfj/googlebook

Comment: I figured it out! I posted an answer with details about how I resolved this, and what the issue was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Final results:**

- [On GitHub](https://github.com/oze4/googlebook)
- [Published to Heroku](https://new-googlybook.herokuapp.com/)

---

**Explanation:**

So, even when running this locally I was getting 404's - the issue turned out to be how you were starting the app.

You only need to start the server, and not the client. It looks like you were starting the "built-in" server that comes with `create-react-app`... so, your server was never actually accepting requests as your front end was running on port 3000 and your backend was running on whatever port you had set in `.env`.

Due to how you have `axios` sending requests (just using the current URL, which was running on the built in `create-react-app` port, not your server port), it was essentially sending requests to the wrong port.

This is something I should have thought of last night, since I remembered seeing your Heroku app was using the development build of React (via the Firefox React extension) - that should have been a red flag.

I have added 2 new `npm` scripts: `npm run begin` and `npm start` (renamed the original `npm start` to `npm run start:original`. `npm run begin` properly builds your front end, and then starts your backend afterwards.  **This is ultimately what resolved the issue**. I also had `NODE_ENV=production` while testing locally.

I also removed `npm heroku-postbuild` as it is not needed.

---

**Code Changes:**

After getting this to work, I noticed there was something wrong with your front end code - a loop was sending the request over and over - I kept seeing the below info logged to the console. So I also resolved that using the code further down (I did not delete any code, I just commented the code out, so that you can see the changes I made).

I don't know where you're using Mongo at but I tested this using Atlas - I had issues talking to the database after deploying to Heroku, so I also had to change how you were connecting to the database in `server.js`. You can also view these changes below, or in the GitHub repo..

Let me know if you want me to send a pull request to your repo so you'll have the updated code and won't have to manually change anything.

Lastly, double check your environmental variables inside Heroku - make sure that they are set.

```
// This kept being logged to the console
...
actually hit the route
actually hit the route
actually hit the route
actually hit the route
actually hit the route
actually hit the route
...
...
// This kept going on and on and on after I searched
```

---

**These are the changes I made to fix the request loop:**

```js
// App.js

function App() {
  /**
   * Separated your state into 2 different variables.
   * Your request loop was happening due to how your 
   * useEffect was configured (specifically the dependency 
   * array)
   */
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState();
  const [searchResults, setSearchResults] = useState();

  /*
  const [search, setSearch] = useState({
    term: '',
    results: []
  });
  */

  useEffect(() => {
    Axios.post(`/api/search`, { term: searchTerm /* search.term */ })
    .then(books => {
      setSearchResults(books.data);
      // setSearch({...search, results: books.data})
    });
  }, [searchTerm]);

  return (
    <div className="app">
      <Header />
      <Router>
        <Route exact path='/'>
          <Searchbar /* search={search} <-- No need for this param */ setSearch={setSearchTerm} /> 
          {!searchTerm /* search.term */ ? (
            <div className="message">
              <p>Search for a book or whatever</p>
            </div>
          ) : <SearchList results={searchResults/* search.results */} />}
        </Route>
        <Route path='/saved'>
          <h2 className="title">Saved Books</h2>
          <SavedList />
        </Route>
        <Footer />
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```js
// Searchbar.js

const Searchbar = ({/* search, */ setSearch}) => { // <-- No need for search param here
    return (
        <form action="#" method="get" className="searchbar" onSubmit={e => e.preventDefault()}>
            <DebounceInput
                minLength={2}
                debounceTimeout={300}
                type="search" 
                placeholder=" search..."
                onChange={(e) => setSearch(e.target.value)}
            />
        </form>
    )
}
```

```js
// server.js

require('dotenv').config();

const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const Axios = require('axios');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;
const mongoUri = process.env.MONGODB_URI || 'mongodb://localhost:27017/book';

const app = express();

// Define middleware here
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Serve up static assets (usually on heroku)
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  app.use(express.static('client/build'));
}

const { Schema } = mongoose;

const bookSchema = new Schema({
  info: Schema.Types.Mixed,
});

// *** REMOVED THIS ***
// const Book = mongoose.model('Book', bookSchema);

// ==========================================================
// **********************************************************
//          CHANGED THE WAY YOU CONNECT TO MONGO
// **********************************************************
// ==========================================================
/** */ mongoose.set('useCreateIndex', true);
/** */ 
/** */ const mongoConnection = mongoose.createConnection(mongoUri, {
/** */   useUnifiedTopology: true,
/** */   useNewUrlParser: true,
/** */   useFindAndModify: false,
/** */ });
/** */ 
/** */ const Book = mongoConnection.model('Book', bookSchema /*, 'COLLECTION_NAME'*/);
// ==========================================================
// **********************************************************
//                      END OF CHANGES
// **********************************************************
// ==========================================================

app.post('/api/search', (req, res) => {
  console.log('actually hit the route');
  Axios.get(
    `https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=${req.body.term}`
  ).then(books => res.json(books.data.items));
});

app.post('/api/save', (req, res) => {
  const newBook = new Book({ info: req.body.book });
  newBook.save(err => {
    if (err) res.json(err);
    res.json({ status: true });
  });
});

app.post('/api/unsave', (req, res) => {
  Book.findByIdAndRemove(req.body.book._id, err => {
    if (err) res.json(err);
    res.json({ status: true });
  });
});

app.get('/api/saved', (req, res) => {
  Book.find({}, (err, books) => {
    if (err) res.json(err);
    else res.json(books);
  });
});

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, './client/build/index.html'));
});

/*
const db = mongoose.connection;

db.on('error', // console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:') 
  error => {
    console.log("[MONGOOSE][ERROR]", error);
  }
);

db.once('open', function() {
  console.log('[MONGOOSE][SUCCESS] Connected to database!');
});
*/

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(` ==> API server now on port ${PORT}!`);
});
```

Comment: Wow thanks for going through the trouble! That was the issue.

Comment: @MarcFariasJones no problem! It was bothering me that I couldn't figure it out lol.. I also just updated my answer with a different method of connecting to Mongo.. I noticed with the old way, after building on Heroku, the build wouldn't ever actually finish - I'm guessing because the Mongo connection being open confused the Heroku builder and it never thought the build finished. The way that I changed the connection to mitigates this issue, and it doesn't occur anymore (but you are still able to access the database, etc..)

Answer (score -1):

if you add a console.log in the api save does it run when hitting that url? Even though it returns a 404 it might still be running possibly.

Comment: agreed. I did jam a console.log in there though and it's not hitting the route.

Comment: you could maybe try to run heroku locally to see if you get the same issues: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-local