# React app with Express backend returns 404 for API calls when hosted on heroku

Tags: reactjs, express, heroku, http-status-code-404

I have been trying to build a simple portfolio with a working contact page, using the nodemailer npm package. The app itself works fine when I run it on my local machine, both in development mode and in production, but when I deploy the app to heroku, I get a 404 error whenever I hit the API route. I've tried everything I can think of, and I can't figure out why it is throwing the 404 for the life of me. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my server.js file

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const path = require('path');

const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
//Serve up static assets (usually on heroku)
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
    app.use(express.static("client/build"));
}


app.post('/contact', function (req, res) {

    console.log("POST ROUTE HIT")

    const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        service: 'gmail',
        auth: {
            user: 'myemail', //NOTE: these are placeholders for my real email / password
            pass: 'mypwd'
        }
    });

    const mailOptions = {
        from: req.body.sender_email,
        to: 'myemail',
        subject: req.body.email_subject + ": from " + req.body.sender_email,
        text: req.body.email_body
    };

    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (error, info) {
        console.log("sending mail...");
        if (error) {
            // res.json(error);
            console.log("Error: " + error)
        } else {
            ;
            console.log("email sent: " + info.data)

        }
    });
});


app.get("*", function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "./client/build/index.html"));

});


// Spin up server
app.listen(PORT, ()=> {
    console.log("app listening on port " + PORT)
})
```

Here is my package.json in the root directory

```
{
  "name": "react-portfolio-w-backend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "react app w/ backend server",
  "main": "server.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.0",
    "concurrently": "^5.2.0",
    "http-proxy-middleware": "^1.0.4",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "nodemailer": "^6.4.6",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "^3.4.1",
    "reactstrap": "^8.4.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "start": "if-env NODE_ENV=production && npm run start:prod || npm run start:dev",
    "start:prod": "set NODE_ENV=production && nodemon server.js",
    "start:dev": "concurrently \"nodemon --ignore 'client/*'\" \"npm run client\"",
    "win:prod": "set NODE_ENV=production && nodemon server.js",
    "client": "cd client && npm run start",
    "seed": "node scripts/seedDB.js",
    "install": "cd client && npm install",
    "build": "cd client && npm run build"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/medricr/react-portfolio-w-backend.git"
  },
  "author": "Medric Riley",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/medricr/react-portfolio-w-backend/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/medricr/react-portfolio-w-backend#readme"
}
```

Here is the API.js file which I use as a reference to call the route from the front end

```
import axios from 'axios';

export default {

    sendEmail: function(info){
        console.log("email info: " + info);
        return axios.post('/contact', info);
    }
}
```

And here is the code snippet used in the actual react component to send the email

```
    sendEmail = () => {
        console.log("sendemail button hit")
        API.sendEmail({
            sender_email: this.state.sender_email,
            email_subject: this.state.email_subject,
            email_body: this.state.email_body
        }).then((result)=> {
            console.log(result);
        })
    }
```

Thank you in advance for any insight you can give into this situation, I'm personally all out of ideas.

**EDIT: ** When I set up my proxy in my package.json file, I was getting an 'Invalid Host Header' error when deploying to heroku, so I tried to set up the proxy manually using the http-proxy-middleware package, using the following code

```
const proxy = require('http-proxy-middleware');

module.exports = function(app){
    app.use(
        proxy(['/contact'], {target: "http://localhost:3001"})
    )
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Do you have a proxy set up for the react app? https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/

Comment: I had the proxy set in my package.json file, but when I deployed to heroku I was getting an "Invalid Host Header" error. I then tried installing the http-proxy-middleware package and configuring the proxy that way. I did not set up the .env.development file in the root however, so I will try that next. Thank you very much.

Comment: @displacedtexan I added the code I used to set up my proxy using http-proxy-middleware to the original question. The syntax I used was different from the example you provided, so I will try editing it to look more like your example next if adding the .env does not get me anywhere.

Comment: Oh man, I had problems getting proxy set up on Heroku. I forget now but I think this might be the right direction: https://github.com/BrightReps/create-react-app-buildpack#user-content-proxy

Comment: Yeah, it's been giving me quite a bit of trouble. The frustrating thing is that I have deployed applications like this to heroku before without this particular problem, so I'm really stumped. Including the .env.development file resulted in the same 404 error, while setting up the proxy using the syntax from the react documentation resulted in a 503, with the app crashing before launch. I will read through the documentation given in your latest reply and see if I get anywhere. Thanks a ton for taking the time to respond!

Answer (score 0):

After doing some more research, I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60348625/api-routes-on-react-express-app-giving-404-on-heroku) answer which helped me solve my problem. The gist of it was that I was using the default scripts included in create-react-app, which were running the built-in client server, and not my actual server.js file. As a result the server was never actually accepting any requests, resulting in a 404 error on my end. I was able to resolve this issue by changing my scripts to match the answer in the question I've hyperlinked.